# Jquery: Action after user finishes typing

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can anyone please help me to understand why I'm getting multiple alerts when I'm typing 3 to 4 characters simultaneously?

I'm trying to display an alert when the user has stopped typing for 250ms

Jquery code:

```js
var time;
$('#uname').keyup(function() {
  clearTimeout(time);
  setTimeout(() => {
    alert(this.value);
  }, 250);
});
```

I understand that this question can seem to be similar to one of the previous questions, but I have tried that solution, and still not able to understand the error.

Comment: `time = setTimeout()` - forgot to set time value, so it's never reset

Comment: stop to infernal cadency!!

Comment: @Frenchy I fail to see how you comment is useful, you should try explain the use what he either did wrong or why he should not do what he does. yelling `stop to infernal cadency` is as useful as yelling `you are doing it wrong.`

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen i speak about question alert when user stops to type during 250ms (french humour with my english)